# My C program counts 1 less number than it should

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a C program that, given a sequence of number, prints to monitor how many numbers are even, odd, null, positive, negative and if the sequence is increasing or decreasing.

The problem, is that my program is counting 1 less number than it should. If I insert 5 numbers, my program will count 4 numbers.

Can anyone help me, please?

```
// Scrivi un programma in C che data una sequenza di numeri stampa i positivi, i negativi, i nulli
// se è pari, se è dispari e di che tipo è la sequenza (crescente, decrescente, indefinita)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int N;

    // Chiedi all'utente il numero di elementi nella sequenza
    printf("Inserisci il numero di elementi nella sequenza: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    // Dichiarazione delle variabili
    int numero, positivi = 0, nulli = 0, negativi = 0, pari = 0, dispari = 0;
    int precedente, crescente = 1, decrescente = 1;

    // Leggi il primo numero per confronto
    printf("Inserisci il primo numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &precedente);

    // Loop per leggere gli N-1 numeri successivi
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        printf("Inserisci il prossimo numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &numero);

        // Conta positivi, nulli e negativi
        positivi += (numero > 0) ? 1 : 0;
        nulli += (numero == 0) ? 1 : 0;
        negativi += (numero < 0) ? 1 : 0;

        // Conta pari e dispari
        pari += (numero % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0;
        dispari += (numero % 2 != 0) ? 1 : 0;

        // Verifica se la sequenza è crescente o decrescente
        crescente = (numero > precedente) ? crescente : 0;
        decrescente = (numero < precedente) ? decrescente : 0;

        // Aggiorna il valore precedente per il prossimo confronto
        precedente = numero;
    }

    system("cls");
    // Stampa dei risultati
    printf("\nRisultati:\n");
    printf("Numeri positivi: %d\n", positivi);
    printf("Numeri nulli: %d\n", nulli);
    printf("Numeri negativi: %d\n", negativi);
    printf("Numeri pari: %d\n", pari);
    printf("Numeri dispari: %d\n", dispari);

    // Stampa della condizione sulla sequenza
    printf((crescente) ? "La sequenza e' crescente.\n" : (decrescente) ? "La sequenza e' decrescente.\n" : "La sequenza non e' ne crescente ne decrescente.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure how to include the first number in the for cycle, or how to make it work.

Comment: What is the input you are providing? What is the expected output? You might consider translating any prompts for data since then I could guess at valid input.

Comment: How many iterations do you think `for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)` executes?

Comment: For the worst case, if `N == 1` does it iterate at all?

Comment: So it is not just *counting* less, it's not even asking for enough inputs.

Comment: Not using English for your variables and comments makes it harder for us to help you.

Comment: The idiom in C is `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)` (start at zero)

Comment: `system("cls")` makes your program Windows specific.  You should tag it as such or use an ansi escape sequence to clear the screen instead.

Comment: Upper case symbols are, by convention, used for constants.

Comment: OT: you should *always* check the function value returned by **`int`** `scanf(...)`. It returns a value apart from the actual input(s) for a reason.

Comment: It's not wrong but using a tertiary when use one side is kinda odd.   Use a regular `if` or go branchless and just the value of the boolean expression.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/205233)

Comment: The question was closed before I could provide you with my answer.  While the loop point is correct in both answers below, neither address the fact that you read a number `precedente` before the loop.   What I suggest eliminate the `scanf` of `precedente` before the loop, modify the prompt in the loop to read `if(i)  printf("Inserisci il prossimo numero: "); else  printf("Inserisci il primo numero: ");` .  Only do `crescente` and `decrescente` `if(i)`.

Comment: Here is how I would do the other counts: `positivi += numero > 0;` and the boolean check `crescente &= numero > precedente;`

Comment: You have some identities you could use `N == positivi + nulli + negativi`, `N == pari + dispari`.  Meaning you can eliminate one of the variables from each of those equations. `crescente = 1 && decrescente == 0 || crescente == 0 && decrescente == 1 || crescente == 0 && decrescente == 0` (so 3 states, you can store that as `-1`, `0`, `1` (in a `signed char` for instance).

Answer (score 1):

You issue is in your loop logic:

```
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
```

For a value of `N = 4`
This will loop for the values: `1`,`2`,`3` but not `4` because 4 is NOT less than `N` => 4 < 4 is not true.

so change your loop to use less than *or* equals to:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
```

This is a common issue with 1 based logic in loops because the comparison is evaluated at the start of each loop cycle and `i` is incremented at the end.

---

- Use `i < N` for zero based indexes in ascending order
- Use `i <= N` for 1 based indexes in ascending order

The reverse is true for descending orders (counting down)

1 based descending:

```
for (int i = N; i > 0 N; i--)
```

zeo based descending:

```
for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0 N; i--)
```